# TODO tasks list in Flash Builder

Tags: flash-builder, task, todo

Does Flash Builder support tasks list?
I'm testing Flash Builder for PHP, and I can see my // TODO in PHP code but not in AS or MXML.
I found this plugin:
http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=911D4B57-0F0D-5A73-AF6F4D4D04099757

but it's very old.

Do you know how can I see my TODO list in AS3 and MXML code with Flash Builder 4.5?


**[UPDATE]:**
I've installed the plugin from richinternet.de and it works in Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP.

But it's very poor, it only detects the TODOs and FIXMEs if you open the file, it doesn't search all your src for TODOs and FIXMEs.

And also is case insensitive, that's a problem for me, because in spanish "todo" means "everything", so I can't use the word todo in my comments now. 


I can't understand how Adobe doesn't include a plugin for this after so many years developing Flash Builder !! they are adding TODO comments when you generate a handler, method, etc !!! I don't know how that can be useful if you don't show it in the tasks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the TODO/FIXME extension for Flash Builder at the following link, and give it a try.

http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=911D4B57-0F0D-5A73-AF6F4D4D04099757

Another link at: http://blog.winnemconsulting.com/2011/08/08/fbtoolkit-taskfixmetodo-plugin-for-flex-and-flashbuilder/

How it works: the plugin parses every MXML/AS file when opened and searches comments (both MXML and AS comments) for TODO and FIXME tokens (this search is case insensitive, so it also finds todo). The same action takes place after a file has been saved. If a token is found, a new Task gets generated with its message set to the comment and displayed in the Task View (To open Task View choose Window-->Other Views...-->Basic-->Tasks in Flex Builder 2 standalone and Window-->Show View-->Other-->Basic-->Tasks when running Flex Builder 2 as a plugin in Eclipse). Note: to really delete a Task you have to delete the comment - deleting a Task from the Task View does not kill the comment, so after you save the file the Task will reappear.

Comment: The link you posted dosn't seem to work anymore.  Does anyone know where I can still download it?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness on this question:

I do agree with you on the fact that it is truely amazing and inconceivable that such features do not exist in Flash Builder by default.

There is another alternative, though it's not free (It does have a 30 day trial though)

It is called SourceMate http://www.elementriver.com/sourcemate

The product has loads of other cool features, be sure to check the feature list.

Answer (score 1):

I commented above on the accepted answer, but I'll relist here...

This post is now seriously outdated :(. I would like to offer a different answer... We'll say starting with Flash Builder 4.6.

---

[image]

It's from a great [article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fcd.html#WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4cf756-7fc9) (from the Adobe Cats) about how to add Task Markers (and Bookmarks) to your Flash Builder Project Files.

Comment: And in Flash Builder 4.7, you can simply right click next to a line number in any ActionScript File and and select 'Add Task'.

Answer (score 0):

You can always search in the solution for "TODO":) And in the results window, press F5 the next time you want to see TODOs.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to install the plugins mentioned previously via the software install menu under Help > Install Software.

WARNING - Don't get the SourceMate plugin if you have FB 4.7 - it isn't supported and doesn't look like it will be soon. Check this page for updates: http://support.elementriver.com/discussions/sourcemate