# Task Tags in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flash-builder

Today I was very happy to see the project properties of the Flex Builder 4.5 a setting named "Task Tags". Looking for a long time I found the settings in the Eclipse Preferences under General -> Editors -> Structured Text -> Task Tags.

I thought that I would finally have the opportunity to create tasks with //TODO in my as and mxml files. Unfortunately I did then the second tab "Filter" found. "Scan the Select Content types" is unequivocal and here are the file types, css, dtd, html and xml.

I would now like to add mxml and as, but that does not seem to be possible. Another possibility would be to take the extension of Dirk, is available [here](http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=911D4B57-0F0D-5A73-AF6F4D4D04099757).

Here I do not like that I can not create their own tags, and this is possible with the out-of-the-box feature of Eclipse. But not for Flex files.

Can someone help me or how did you solve this?
Thanks and best regards
Frank

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234441/todo-tasks-list-in-flash-builder

Comment: I my opinion, this is not a duplicate. i want here to know, if its possible to add some filetypes in eclipse, because i don't like the extension. My question has the focus on eclipse settings. If you think anyway, this is a dublicate, sorry!

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This refers to the preferences. Not the plugin.

Comment: Clicking on one of those file types will then fill the lower pane with all of its subtypes, which are also scanned.  Are the *.mxml files not a subtype of XML?